# Passing received `.xlsx` file from Laravel application to Nextjs front end ui

Tags: node.js, laravel, next.js, laravel-excel

I made a request from Nextjs front end ui to Nextjs api and this api send another request to Laravel application to generate an Excel file and return the Excel file to Nextjs api. And finally serve the Excel to the ui as attachment. So far my code is messed up and I really hope someone could come up with proper yet elegant way to for this case.

Comment: It would be helpful to show a sample code you think has issues in the process, then it becomes easy for someone to help. However with the look of things, I think it would be better for you to return a url to download the excel file, then use `window.location.href = 'myurl'`

Comment: I think that's good idea but I'll end up to clean up the with storage issue